# reading multiple XQuery files from BaseX command line?

Tags: xquery, basex

I have an existing project running on some other XQuery processor/platform and would like to try it out with [BaseX](https://basex.org/).

Basically I have Xquery query expressions defined in multiple files to have some sort of "modules".

```
(: q1.xq :)
declare function local:fun1() {};
```

```
(: q2.xq :)
declare function local:fun2() {};
```

```
(: main.xq :)
declare function local:main() {
  let $a := local:fun1()
  let $b := local:func2()
};
```

and

```
$ xq_processor -q q1.xq -q q2.xq -q main.xq
```

however it does not work with

```
$ basex q1.xq q2.xq main.xq
```

the function definition is not visible to each other (i.e.[XPST0017] Unknown function)

how can I achieve this in BaseX? from command line

*(Alternatively, I may probably need to use `xquery:eval` in main.xq to read q1.xq and x2.xq...)*

Comment: Perhaps use a command line shell specific command to concatenate the three files and then feed that concatenated file as the input to basex e.g. with Windows Powershell for me it works to use `Get-Content .\q1.xq, .\q2.xq, .\main.xq | & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\BaseX\bin\basex.bat' -` (after fixing your function declarations to use `declare function` instead of `declare`).

Comment: I think with Bash you should be able to use `cat q1.xq q2.xq main.xq | basex -`.

Comment: yes, it is probably the most practical way!